# R variable inside a string

Tags: r, string, variables, arguments

I would like to know if it is possible to pass a variable inside a string with R like in php. For example:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
variable1 <- args[1]

variable2 <- "I am argument:",variable1,"text continue"
```

Comment: I'd use `sprintf`.

Comment: I tried with sprintf but with no success. I mean I didn't get what I wanted. variable2 <- sprintf("I am a string %s %s",variable1,"text continue")

Comment: `sprintf("I am a string %s text continue", variable1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
variable2 <- paste0("I am argument:",variable1,"text continue")
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There are variety of ways to get the output :

```
variable1 <- args[1]
```

1) Using `sprintf` as mentioned by @Roland

```
sprintf("I am argument: %s text continue",variable1)
```

2) Using `glue`

```
glue::glue("I am argument: {variable1} text continue")
```

3) a) `str_c`

```
stringr::str_c("I am argument:",variable1,"text continue")
```

b) `stri_c`

```
stringi::stri_c("I am argument:",variable1,"text continue")
```